# Visualforce page not displaying correct Devnagiri words when it render as pdf

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using Arial Unicode MS font in the visual force page. I need to render it as pdf. The HTML contains Devanagari words. HTML is displayed properly but the words are broken in the generated pdf. e.g `"मास्टर" => मास् टर` Has anybody faced this problem?

Comment: Do you mind posting the minimal reproducible code here? From [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm) the behavior can be different when viewing on browser vs. rendered pdf -- [*Viewing pages in a web browser can have different results.*]

Comment: I don't read Devanagari, so forgive the stupid question - does this piece of text include combining characters or diacritics? I'm wondering if the old PDF renderer Salesforce uses is choking on the particular Unicode representation being used.